# auto increment field doesn't

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, parsing-error

I have created  a `st_Age` table in Visual C# with these columns and types

- `id` (have increment property by 1 and assigned as primary key)
- `Name` (nvarchar(50))
- `age` (int)

It shows no errors when completing the source code, but in running I get this error message:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'st_Age' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I tried to solve the problem from Tool menu with no success.

Can anybody teach me the right way to solve the problem.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Can you past your code ?

Comment: You don't have to assign a value to the `Id` column.

Comment: Remove adding identity column

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying a value for the column id in the INSERT statement as the error message says.

Answer (score 0):

identity column would have its value if you insert a new row. You ll have to leave identity column while inserting a new row. If you would like to insert a value for identity column also, then set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the code is as following:
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(txtName.Text!="" || txtAge.Text!="")
            {
               cn.Open();
               cmd.CommandText=@"Insert into st_Age(id,name,age) values (1,'"+txtName+"','"+txtAge+"') ";
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Clone();
            MessageBox.Show("A Row is inserted","Programming is funny");
          //  cn.Close();

```
        }
```

....................................................................
it may be the table variables error I don't know but i used visual studio 2012
to build the database(not ms sql server standalone version)